# slim optional route parameter suffix not working

Tags: slim

I want to define a route which have a .suffix param in the end. I want to use it in my app to return what user needs. Eg .json or .xml or none!. How should I define my route? This is an example address I want:

```
/user/all.json
```

or

```
/user/all.xml
```

or

```
/user/all # default json
```

This is the route i defined. But it's not working as expected.

```
/user/:method(\.(:type))
```

Comment: There is an accept header for this: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Comment: In this project, I need to get the user to determine the output format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Slim route segments are defined by a forward slash, and not interchangeably with a dot. However, you can either add logic to the route closure, or add route conditions to multiple routes.

In the closure:

```
$app->get('/user/:methodtype', function ($methodtype) {
    if ($path = explode($methodtype, '.')) {
        if ($path[1] === 'json') {
            // Something to do with json...
        } elseif ($path[1] === 'xml') {
            // Something to do with xml...
        }
    }
});
```

Or use route conditions, one for each so they are mutually exclusive:

```
// JSON requests
$app->get('/user/:methodtype', function ($methodtype) {
    // Something to do with json...
})->conditions(array('methodtype' => '.json$'));

// XML requests
$app->get('/user/:methodtype', function ($methodtype) {
    // Something to do with xml...
})->conditions(array('methodtype' => '.xml$'));
```